# How to deploy the built docker image built by Cloud Build on Cloud Run automatically

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

Currently I trigger a `Cloud Build` each time a pull request is completed.

The image is built correctly, but we have to manually go to `Edit and Deploy New Revision` and select the most recent docker image to deploy.
How can we automate this process and have the a container deployed from the image automatically?

Comment: Have you checked the [Continuous deployment from Git](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a pretty simple GitHub Action. I have followed this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-to-google-cloud-run-using-github-actions-590ecf957af0

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run also [natively integrates with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/cloud-run-integrates-with-continuous-deployment). You can import a GitHub repository and it sets up a GCB trigger for your repository (on the specified branch or tag filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitLab CI to automate your Cloud Run deployment.

Here are the tutorial if you want to automate your deployment with GitLab CI [Link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-to-cloud-run-using-gitlab-ci-e056685b8eeb)